Closure of the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of a closed, bounded set
While trying to prove some result in topology, I thought I could try proving the following lemma: if $X$ is a metric space and $C$ is a closed, bounded subset of $X$ then for $\epsilon > 0$, the "closed $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $C$", defined as the set of points in $X$ whose distance to some point in $C$ is at most $\epsilon$, is closed.
This result seems true to me in this general setting, but if necessary $X$ can be assumed to be a Hilbert space.
Here is my longest attempt to proving it:
Without loss of generality, let $V$ be the $1$-neighbourhood of $C$ and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of elements in $V$ that converges towards some $x \in X$. Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence of elements of $C$ such that for all $n$, $d(x_n, y_n) \le 1$. Then we have: $d(x, y_n) \le d(x, x_n) + d(x_n, y_n)$. Taking $\limsup$ on both sides, we get $\limsup d(x, y_n) \le 1$, so the largest limit point of $(d(x, y_n))$ is at most $1$. If it is strictly less than $1$ then we'll be able to find some $y_n$ which is close enough to $x$ to ensure $x \in V$. But if $\limsup (d(x, y_n)) = 1$ then there is no guarantee it ever reaches a value less than or equal to $1$. So I'm stuck at that point.
My intuition is that it could be useful to find a smarter way to construct $(y_n)$, for example to ensure they get close enough to one another (or at least, a subsequence of it does) as $n$ gets bigger. But I can't find a procedure.
Any confirmation that the result I'm trying to prove is true (or not) and hint towards a proof would be appreciated.

Another counterexample is $X = \Bbb Q$ with the usual metric, and $C = (\sqrt 2, 2] \cap \Bbb Q$, and $\epsilon = \sqrt 2$.

The claim is in fact false.
Consider $\ell^2$ and the set
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
C = \{ \hspace{-10pt} & (2, 0, 0, 0, \ldots), & \\
& (0, \frac{3}{2}, 0, 0, \ldots), & \\
& (0, 0, \frac{4}{3}, 0, \ldots), & \\
& (0, 0, 0, \frac{5}{4}, \ldots), & \\
& \ldots & \hspace{-10pt} \} \\
\end{array}
$$
$C$ is closed (even discrete). Take $\varepsilon = 1$. Let $M = \{x \in \ell^2 \mid \exists y \in C : \|x - y\|_2 \leq \varepsilon\}$. Clearly, we have
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
\{ \hspace{-10pt} & (1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots), & \\
& (0, \frac{1}{2}, 0, 0, \ldots), & \\
& (0, 0, \frac{1}{3}, 0, \ldots), & \\
& (0, 0, 0, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots), & \\
& \ldots & \hspace{-10pt} \} \subseteq M \\
\end{array}
$$
However, it is also clear that $(0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots) \not\in M$. Hence $M$ is not closed.
